# Octave: can compile mex, but get error: "failed to install .mex file function"

Tags: ubuntu, octave, mex

I am trying to convert a piece of code from Matlab to python. I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS and need to rely on Octave to run the reference code (Matlab does not install with an esotheric error). Anyway, having never used Octave before it is possible I have missed a step, but I cannot find the solution after spending a day searching all around the internet.

Part of the code uses a mex file. I can compile it with `mkoctfile --mex gradientMex.cpp` or `mex --mex gradientMex.cpp`. I get no output, but a `gradientMex.mex` file is generated in my working directory. However, when I try to use `gradientMex()` I get the error `failed to install .mex file function 'gradientMex'`. Is there something I need to do after compiling the mex file?

In case it is of any use, the project I am converting is https://github.com/autocyz/DSST , I needed to copy some of the dependencies from here: https://github.com/pdollar/toolbox/tree/1a3c9869033548abb0c7a3c2aa6a7902c36f39c2/channels/private (`wrappers.hpp` and `sse.hpp`)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe compiling with `mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE gradientMex.cpp` ?

Comment: Looks like it works! I am getting another unrelated error now. Will fix that and if you submit your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source code of this particular project, the code needed to load mex files into matlab/octave is included in a `#ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE` section, but `mkoctfile` doesn't define that variable by default. So

```
mkoctfile --mex -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE gradientMex.cpp
```

keeps you going. However, you are exploring a territory where compatibility between matlab and octave is really minimal, and I would expect other errors. YMMV, but perhaps installing matlab might prove less painful than porting the project to octave, especially if your matlab licence includes installation support. Good luck.